# SQL string remove a substring of unknown length

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, text, format

A very simple problem in SQL that I don't seem to find an easy solution to.

> @Input: 'GoodFilter in (2, 3, 100) and BadFilter in (11, 23, 24, 25) and AnotherFilter in (1, 2)'
>
> @DesiredOutput: 'GoodFilter in (2, 3, 100) and AnotherFilter in (1, 2)'

I really would like a simple one line solution to this. Something I tried but with no result:

`SELECT REPLACE(@Input, 'BadFilter in (%%) and ', '')`

Code example:

```
DECLARE @Input nvarchar(500) = 'GoodFilter in (2, 3, 100) and BadFilter in (11, 23, 24, 25) and AnotherFilter in (1, 2)'
DECLARE @DesiredOutput nvarchar(500) = 'GoodFilter in (2, 3, 100) and AnotherFilter in (1, 2)'
--do magic to remove BadFilter
--@Input == @DesiredOutput
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: pls set up a reproduceable code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use charindex and replace in sql server

```
select left(@Input, charindex('BadFilter',@Input) - 1) + 
right(@Input, len(@Input) - charindex('AnotherFilter',@Input) + 1)
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't define the problem to full because AnotherFilter not always exists, meaning the BadFilter is sometimes the last one in the string. But this answer is definitely a good one because i could just build my input a bit differently by putting the BadFilter in the end and then using LEFT on it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from zip i got another idea.
I changed the @Input so that the BadFilter always comes last in the @Input.
And then the solution looks like:

```
DECLARE @Input nvarchar(500) = 'GoodFilter in (123,123,123) and AnotherFilter in (1,2,3,4) and BadFilter in (1,2,3)'
SELECT LEFT(@Input, CHARINDEX(' and BadFilter', @Input))
```